# Use a user supplied value as the value of the Wix attribute

Tags: wix, event-log, wix3.5, wix-extension

I want to know if it's possible to have the user who is installing the package to supply the value of the eventsource name.

```
<util:EventSource Log="Application" Name="WixSample" SupportsErrors ="yes" SupportsInformationals ="yes" SupportsWarnings ="yes" EventMessageFile="%SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\EventLogMessages.dll" KeyPath="yes"/>
```

So in the above example I would like the user entered value to be the Name attribute.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can be a property. So, you should be able to do:

```
<util:EventSource Name="[USER_PROVIDED_VALUE]" ...
```